# How to properly esca‌​pe spaces in the res‌​ults of mdfind to use them in a for loop

Tags: macos, bash, spotlight, script

Trying to answer the question [Are true dynamic folders (NOT a “Smart Folder” SavedSearch) possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280950/are-true-dynamic-folders-not-a-smart-folder-savedsearch-possible) I stumbled about the problem to loop the results of an mdfind search as quoted or escaped paths.

Code snippet:

```
for File in $(mdfind -onlyin $MusicSamples 'kMDItemAudioBitRate >= "44000"  && _kMDItemUserTags = "Sample"')
do
    ln -s $File $DrumFoldr
done
```

The ***for*** loop should create soft links of all matching files in the folder $MusicSamples or its sub folders in the folder $DrumFoldr. The loop works for files with paths/file names without spaces.

- The answer to a [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205605/how-to-escape-spaces-in-the-results-of-mdfind) question simply suggests to quote $File (`... "$File" ...`). This doesn't work - it simply creates broken soft links with names of the contiguous strings in the original file name: a file named "1. Artist - Song - Mix.mp3" will create four or five soft links: "1.", "Artist", "Song", "Mix.mp3"  and "-".
- Escaping the spaces by piping the mdfind results to a sed command replacing a space with an escaped space `\`  will result in something like "\ 1.", "\ Artist" etc.
- [Creating an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092245/filter-bad-path-results-in-mdfind) of the mdfind results with:

  ```
  result=()
  mdfind ... | while IFS= read -r filename; do
    result+=("$filename")
  done
  ```

  and using it in `for File in "${result[@]}"; do ln -s "$File" $DrumFoldr; done` doesn't work either.

How do I properly escape those spaces in the paths?

Comment: `mdfind` has a null option. You could then try piping the results through `xargs`.

Comment: @fd0 I tried this also (haven't mentioned it in my question though) - without success. But I may have made a mistake in the command.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle filepaths with funny characters is to use null delimiters (as fd0 suggested in a comment). `mdfind -0` will use this output format, very much like `find ... -print0`. You can then parse & use the results with `xargs -0`:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin "$MusicSamples" 'kMDItemAudioBitRate >= "44000"  && _kMDItemUserTags = "Sample"' |
    xargs -0 -J % ln -s % "$DrumFoldr"
```

(Note that I also double-quoted `$MusicSamples` and `$DrumFoldr`, to prevent trouble if either of those contain spaces. Double-quoting variable references is almost always a good idea. Also, this `xargs` invocation will pass many filepaths with each run of `ln` -- if this is a problem, you may need to add something like `-n1` to make it pass them one-by-one.)

If you need to do something more complicated than `xargs` can handle easily, you can also use a shell `while read` loop with some special options:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin "$MusicSamples" 'kMDItemAudioBitRate >= "44000"  && _kMDItemUserTags = "Sample"' |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        ln -s "$file" "$DrumFoldr"
    done
```

(The special options used with `read` are: `-d ''` to make it use nulls as delimiters, `-r` to tell it not to do weird things with backslashes, and `IFS=` to prevent it from trimming whitespace from the beginning or end of the lines.)

See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more info and options.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem as I was trying to iterate over mdfind's results of an image search.

```
counter=0
mdfind image -onlyin $1 | while read line; do 
    ((counter = counter + 1))
    echo "$counter: $line"
done
exit
```

So adapting that to your problem, this should work:

```
mdfind -onlyin $MusicSamples 'kMDItemAudioBitRate >= "44000" && _kMDItemUserTags = "Sample"' | while read File
do
    ln -s "$File" "$DrumFoldr"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you I recently found out why the following does not work for me:

```bash
    result=()
    mdfind ... | while IFS= read -r filename; do
     result+=("$filename")
    done
```

According some research on other sites:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered

So following the CSV example in that answer I can confirm the following works for me:

```bash
    while read -r line; do
     result+=("$line")
    done <<< "$(mdfind "kMDItemAppStoreCategory == 'Productivity'")"
```